# IndexOutOfBounds error, hangman game

Tags: java

I'm making a quick hangman game, and came across an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and was wondering why. I don't see the problem/how this error would come about.

It happens at this line:

```
array[index]+=c;
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        String[] phrase={"television"};
        String[] array= new String[phrase.length];
        int body =6;
        while(array!=phrase) {
            char c=(char)System.in.read();
            int index= console.nextInt();
            array[index]+=c;
            if(array[index].charAt(index)==phrase[index].charAt(index)){
                System.out.println("the new array");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jens it's declared here: `int index= console.nextInt();`, the question is what is the input provided..

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace.

Comment: @Ori Lentz What do you mean?

Comment: There are many problems with how you are handling arrays, and I think you are creating them not the way you intend them to be. Look up this basic tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm. It should clear up a few things

Comment: To clear things up the user types a character presses enter, and then types in a number which represents the spot where they want to put the letter at. This number would represent an in index in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many Issues with the code. few of them are below.

- you are creating array of size "phrase.length" which will be of size 1, when i enter 2 for "console.nextInt();" it will throw index out of bound.
- Array Equality check is wrong, you need to do something like

  if( Arrays.equals(array1, array2) )

Comment: omg u r a genius thanks a bunch!!!